# Replacing a ceiling fan with light kit on 3-way circuit

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan

How do I wire a replacement ceiling fan on a 3-way circuit? I have four supply wires; red, white, black and ground. Do I just hook it up the way the old fan was wired or is there any rewiring i need to do in the fan itself? The old fan was wired; ground to ground, black to black, white to white and red to blue.
The wall switches are two 3-way switches with the fan in the middle. The switches supply power to the fan then you control the light and fan with the pull strings on the fan itself.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What wires are on the new fan?

Comment: The wire colors matings you have suggested is typical for a ceiling fan.  However, perhaps you should explain what switches are used.

Comment: The new fan has Ground (GRN), Hot (BLK), Neutral (WHT), Light (BLU).

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Which box would you like? I have two wall boxes and the one for the fan.

Comment: @GJNewMex -- if you wish to post photos of all of them, that's even better.

Comment: 3 way means generally 2 separate wall switches. A red is a traveller to pass power between the 2 switches, now, if you have a wall switch with a dimmer and switch, or 2 switches in one, then you could have a red as a light or fan control. Depends on how it's setup. But generally if you have a switch that controls power to the fan setup, then the light and fan wires are combined in the box, to black from the ceiling.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Black is fan , red is light. In other words.,black to black ., red to blue, white to white, ground/bare to green. it will still be a three way and use pull chains individually when power is supplied to the fan.